# Arraylist search

Tags: c#, arraylist

SO I'm working on a program and I want to search for a certain word, but I'm not all too sure how to set up a search function. This is what I was attempting to use, but all it is doing is output whatever I type in. Any help with this is appreciated!

```
    static void searchWords(ArrayList arlWords)
    {
        string strInput;

        Console.Write("Search a Word: ");
        strInput = Console.ReadLine();
        arlWords.IndexOf(strInput, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", strInput);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with *search* for a word: what are you planning to do with it later on in your program?

Comment: It would just search for a word that I have already put in, and tell me if I have it or not

Comment: since your method takes in a list, you could start of with writing the code for finding the word in that "list"

Comment: Search for iteration/looping through a List, also **do not use ArrayList, use `List<T>`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
static void searchWords(ArrayList arlWords)
{
  string strInput;
  bool check= false;
  Console.Write("Search a Word: ");
  strInput = Console.ReadLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < arlWords.Items.Count; i++)
  {
     if (arlWords.Items[i] == strInput )
        check = true;
  }
  if(check) Console.WriteLine("found");
  else Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

Comment: Where does the arrSample come from?

Comment: Thanks for the warning, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You have defined it to write 'strInput' so that it will write.  Instead you should catch the result of 'IndexOf' and print that - or whether it is greater than 0 or not.